# Trying execute Join with empty data frame table return error columns not found

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

We have data(Tables) in S3 bucket(parquet) and need to apply join transformation and Store the result in S3. In the first execution of the job one side of join will be empty.

But i got error, the job not found columns on the side that the table is empty

code

```
df_pos_mov = df_pos_mov.join(df_sum_d0, ["conta","id_ativo","id_operacao", "ano", "mes", "dia"], 'full_outer')
```

error

> 'USING column `conta` cannot be resolved on the right side of the
> join. The right-side columns: []

the right side returns

++ || ++ ++

Comment: Could you please add the output of `df_pos_mov.printSchema()` before the join?

Comment: the side empty returns ++ || ++ ++ without name of columns

Comment: I would guess that the the parquet file for `df_pos_mov` is somehow damaged. `printSchema()` should return the correct columns even if there is no data in the file.

Comment: After i  execute printSchema()  (before join) my df is empty and without columns yet